# Datetime of format yy/mm/dd

Tags: python

i am getting this error please assist.

> ValueError: time data '990415' does not match format '%yy/%mm/%dd'
>   (match)

code:

```
total_data['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(total_data['id'].str.split().str[0], format='%y/%m/%d')
```

dataframe:

```
id
990415
830418
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 10.8. Dates and Times](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#dates-and-times)

Answer (score 0):

To convert column `id` you can apply this

```
total_data['DOB'] = total_data['id'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%y%m%d"))
```

To convert single values use

```
dob = datetime.strptime("990415","%y%m%d"))
```

Comment: @TsepoMokau your're welcome, may be upvote when you find something useful.